# Regex to replace < or > with &gt; or &lt; inside html tag

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

for example.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>-----> hello! ----< </h1>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to replace the > and < inside the h1 tag with the corresponding > and <

which is the correct pattern?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this broken HTML being generated in the first place?

Comment: sorry I forgot the last </html> close.( but is only an exaple )

Comment: No, it's broken even with the `</html>`.

Comment: this is generated from a part that I can't control and I want to replace those charachter automatically

Comment: You can not match a structured language like HTML using a regular expression.  For that matter, what would you do if the screwy text were `<h1> <script type="text/javascript">location.href = 'http://badsite.example.org'</script>`?  The tags match up, but you still really don't want that happening.  You need to sanitize your input before it gets there.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control for that input

Comment: there is no reliable way of doing this using regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw it at `tidy` (see [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)) and see if it can fix the errors. A lot better than trying to do the "right thing" on your own with regex.

```
$html = <<<EOT
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>-----> hello! ----< </h1>
</div>
</body>
EOT;

$config = array ( 
  'clean'                       => true, 
  'drop-proprietary-attributes' => true, 
  'output-xhtml'                => false, 
  'show-body-only'              => false, 
  'wrap'                        => '0'
); 

$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo tidy_get_output($tidy);
```

It might be that you must enable tidy first in your PHP environment.

Comment: Probably I've solve it with tidy. I've already used tidy fot this case. But maybe I'm doing some instructions before that invalidate the tidy function.

Answer (score 2):

In agreement with the commenter "Why is this broken HTML being generated in the first place?", if you represent documents like this then you will have exactly these problems that you are currently having. There are two valid situations

- You have some data (not HTML escaped) e.g. a bunch of strings in PHP
- You have an HTML document, containing tags, and text which is HTML escaped

So when you generate the HTML document from your source data (strings, database) you need to do the escaping them (e.g. by using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) as another answerer correctly pointed out.)

You need to avoid, at all costs, a situation where you have a string like you have, which has HTML tags and non-escaped text.

For example, if you text contained the text `<b>text</b>` and you literally wanted that text to be displayed in the HTML document i.e. you wanted the angle-brackets to be seen rather than the text be in bold (e.g. you were writing a document about how to program HTML) then you have no way to differentiate that from actual HTML code once you have such a document.

Comment: I don't have control about the html. Is from a site that I do not have control. I have to match with xpath the contents inside the html tags and if I find < or > inside tags the xpath query brakes. I hope I've explaned it better :)

Comment: You have to go to whoever **is** controlling the HTML and tell them that the **situation is unacceptable**. I know that doesn't sound like a good answer, but they are sending you invalid and ambiguous data. Like I said, what if the data actually contained the text `<b>` and you wanted to display it, you would have no way to differentiate that from an actual bold tag. Therefore, there cannot be a solution. You need to explain that to them, maybe point to this SO question. Any tools you will try and use (like XPath) also won't work, for the same reason.

Comment: thanks but I'm not in touch with who are giving me the HTML. Anyway maybe I've solved it using Tidy function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would pass it through [tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

Comment: I tried console tidy before writing this and it does exactly what you want.